# How to fix invalid input syntax for type boolean: "abc" in Django and Postgres SQL?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django models with a duplicate field name `trading` I didn't noticed at the time I ran `makemigration` followed by the `migrate` command (both commands didn't throw any error). As you can see in the model.py below, the name "trading" is used for a BooleanField and a CharField.

But now I would like to remove or rename one of them and Django throws an error saying:

```
django.db.utils.DataError: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "future"
```

I'm not familiar with Postgres SQL and have no clue how to solve this problem without destroying and recreating the databse from scratch.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account', null=True)
    strategy = models.ForeignKey(Strategy, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='account', null=True)
    limit_order, credentials, trading = [models.BooleanField(default=True) for i in range(3)]
    trading = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True, choices=[('future', 'future'),
                                                                              ('swap', 'swap')
                                                                              ])
```

I've try to first rename the `CharField` from `trading` to `instrument` but in the migration file it looks like Django wants to add a new field. The problem is that everything I modify in my models generate an error. How can I fix this issue while preserving the database?

This is the first migration file that generated the error:

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.6 on 2020-07-16 10:11

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('trading', '0011_auto_20200714_0758'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='account',
            name='instrument',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('future', 'future'), ('swap', 'swap')], max_length=12, null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='account',
            name='trading',
            field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
        ),
    ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question since I successfully fixed the problem by:

- keep the first migration file that caused the problem and removing the others
- remove all reference to the duplicate fields in my models
- then modify the file as bellow

From :

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='account',
        name='instrument',
        field=models.CharField(blank=True, choices=[('future', 'future'), ('swap', 'swap')], max_length=12, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='account',
        name='trading',
        field=models.BooleanField(default=True),
    ),
]
```

To :

```
operations = [
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='account',
        name='trading',
    ),
]
```